# What is the meathod of Undetermined Coefficients for 1st order ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

As an alternative way to solve $dy/dt=ay-b$, we can solve the simpler version $dy/dt=ay$.  So since it seems that they only differ by a constant, $-b$, we should be able to test this by finding a constant, $k$, such that $y=y_1(t)+k$ is a solution to  $dy/dt=ay-b$, where $y_1(t)$ is the solution of $dy/dt=ay$.

---

From $dy/dt=ay$, I solved to find $y_1(t)=ce^a$ but I'm not sure how this relates to $y_1(k)$. Should I solve $dy/dt=ay-b$ as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry - there were typos. :/

Substitute so that $dy/dt=ay-b=0$ becomes $dy/dt=a(Pt+Q)-b=0$ and then find $P$ and $Q$?  How does this equation or $P$, $Q$,  relate to the $y_1(k)$, $y_1(t)$, or $k$?

Comment: I used a perhaps unnecessarily complicated guess. It turns out that $P=0$ and $Q$ (for $a\ne 0$) is \frac{b}{a}$. Have given details in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $a=0$ is simple to handle, so we assume that $a\ne 0$. "Guess" that the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=ay-b$ has a solution of the shape $y=K$, where $K$ is a constant. Then substitute in the equation to find the $K$ that works.

We get $0=aK-b$, so, since $a\ne 0$, we get $K=\frac{b}{a}$.

We then add this "particular solution" to the "general solution" $y=Ce^{at}$ of the homogeneous equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=ay$ to find the general solution of the equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=ay-b$.

Deciding on the shape we should guess is a matter of experience. The particular example is much simpler than most. In the Wikipedia discussion of the Method, there is a list of useful "guesses" for various common forms of the inhomogeneous term.

'

Answer (score 1):

We have $$y' + ay = -b$$
Well, multiply this equation by $e^{at}$.

Then
$$\frac{d}{dt}(ye^{at}) = - e^{at}b$$
Integrating:
$$ye^{at} = -\frac{b}{a}e^{at}$$
Then
$$y = -\frac{b}{a}.$$